# In Emacs ECB how can I tell if I am in Directories browser or in a buffer?

Tags: emacs

I am using the Emacs Code Browser and I want to be able to programmatically find out if I am in the directory browser or in a code buffer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (if (string-match "*ECB" (buffer-name))
    (print "In ECB")
    (print "NOT in ECB")
  )
```